# process template around how devdiv's work item on TFS

Tags: tfs

Anyone who is familiar w/MS devDiv team's use around TFS.
http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffbe/archive/2008/04/20/how-devdiv-uses-tfs.aspx

I am looking for a process template they used around
work item item template in valuepoposition/experiences/features.

let me know if you know any location I can download their work item template.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://mpt.codeplex.com/

This is very similar to the process template that is used internally, but packaged up and scrubbed by one of the Team System MVP's ([Ed Blankenship](http://www.edsquared.com/)).

It requires use of SQL Server Enterprise Edition currently for the TFS Datastore to have all the reports working.  Obviously this doesn't present a problem for Microsoft as SQL doesn't cost them much but this is not the edition of SQL that is included in the cost of TFS so you may have issues with using it in your company.

If not, go crazy.

Good luck,

Martin.